# Winapi c++, можно ли убрать кнопку развернуть?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

хочу что бы в прога сохраняла свой размер
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно, чтобы при создании окна был сброшен бит `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX`. Например, в VC++ стандартная заготовка использует `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` — достаочно просто вырезать из него `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX`:

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW&~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопка удалена. Только вот это не мешает изменению размера окна перетягиванием границ... Для этого надо еще и убрать там же флаг `WS_SIZEBOX`.